# Why does Object._proto_ refer to Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am looking at this diagram below in the relationship between objects and functions and I am wondering why the Object.*proto* refers to Function.prototype?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__proto__` refers to an object's immediate prototype ancestor. For a simple example `obj` is the immediate ancestor of `obj2`:

```
let obj = {}
// make obj2 with obj parent
let obj2 = Object.create(obj)
obj === obj2.__proto__ // true
```

In the case of your diagram, it is showing the prototype chain from a function to the `Function.prototype` to the `Object.prototype`. You can follow it like a chain:

```js
function test(){}

console.log(test.__proto__ === Function.prototype)
console.log(test.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype)

// alternatively:
Object.getPrototypeOf(test) // Function.prototype
```

In your example `Object.__proto__` is the `Function.prototype` because `Object` is a contructor function in the same way `String` and `Number` are functions. But this isn't the same thing as `Object.prototype` which is the object other object's `__proto__` property point to:

```js
console.log (Object)
console.log(typeof Object)

// call the function to create an object
let o = Object()
// o's prototype is the Object prototype
console.log (o.__proto__ === Object.prototype)
```

Comment: I am aware I am asking why Objects _proto_ refers to function.prototype and not Object.prototype ?

Comment: that is where I am confused you said an Object is a function but isnt everything in js an Object so isnt it the other way around a function is an object? which is why I dont know why the proto of object is pointing to function.proto? So why is type of object a function?

Comment: @akotch Yes, everything is an object, but `Object()` is a function you can call it and make an object. And it **is** confusing because of the naming of things like prototype that mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: @Hamms I think the OP is reading the arrows correctly, `Object.__proto__` points to the function prototype because `Object` is the object constructor function.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think you got it, your right I think the distinction is that the Object in this diagram is a wrapper class, so essentially its a function called Object and not the Object type itself?